# Creating a subclass from an abstract class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

Currently learning about Java and I have a question about making a subclass from an abstract class. I have this:

```
public abstract class Bike
{
  private int cost;

  public Bike(){}

  public abstract void displayCost();
}


public class SportsBike extends Bike
{
  private int topSpeed();

  ???
}

public class CasualBike extends Bike
    {
      private int brakeSpeed();

      ???
    }


 public void main()
{
  SportsBike b1 = new SportsBike(???);
  CasualBike b2 = new CasualBike(???);
}
```

How would I have the constructor for both sportsBike and casualBike so that they would have their own information?? I have read things about @super and such but I am not sure how to implement it. Would @override work if I have multiple class inheriting one class?

Comment: is the constructor argument common for both classes SportsBike and CasualBike?

Comment: Just add the constructors you want to `SportsBike` and `CasualBike` and set whatever you want in them. Know that even if you don't call the superclass constructor in the subclass constructors, it will be called for you, but it will be executed before the subclass constructors, so you can initialize your member variables as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example that you can play around to see how constructors work, and how super class constructors are called automatically even if you don't explicitly call them:

```
public class Parent {
    protected int parentVariable;
    public Parent(){
        parentVariable=1;
        System.out.println("parent no-argument constructor");
    }
    public Parent(int value) {
        System.out.println("parent int constructor");
        parentVariable = value;
    }
    public int getParentVariable() {
        return parentVariable;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    private int childVariable;

    public Child() {
        // Call super() is automatically inserted by compiler
        System.out.println("child no-argument constructor");
        childVariable = 99;
    }
    public Child(int value, int childValue){
        // Explicit call to parent constructor
        super(value);
        System.out.println("child int constructor");
        childVariable = childValue;
    }
    public int getChildVariable() {
        return childVariable;
    }
}   

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Child c1 = new Child();
        Child c2 = new Child(3,199);

        System.out.println(c1.getParentVariable());
        System.out.println(c2.getParentVariable());

        System.out.println(c1.getChildVariable());
        System.out.println(c2.getChildVariable());
    }

}
```

Comment: How would it work if the child or subclass has their own variables to initialize?

Comment: You'd just use the child/subclass constructor to initialize the variables, just as you would with a class that doesn't extend any other class (other than implicitly extending `Obect`,obviously).   I've edited the answer to show a simple example.

Comment: Thanks you for the example!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `cost` is common for both `CasualBike` and `SportsBike`.

Use super keyword to call these two classes and form objects of them.

```
public class SportsBike extends Bike
{
     SportsBike(int cost){
       super(cost);
  }

}
```

and your abstract class should be like :

```
public abstract class Bike
{
  private int cost;

  public Bike(cost){
this.cost=cost;
}
}
```

Comment: So, would this work to initialize topSpeed in SportsBike?


SportsBike(int cost, int speed)
{
  super(cost);
  topSpeed = speed;
}